# send metrics to datadog from ec2 datadog agent when syatemctl is used to stop kafka-connect- worker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka-connect, datadog

My Kafka-worker-connect and Datadog agent on ec2 and sends metric to Datadog. when I use systemctl stop Kafka-worker-connect, its shutting down the whole application without sending the metric to datadog. I tried curl delete operation to stop Kafka its working but it gonna delete the Kafka-connect.

so, I want to run systemctl stop command to stop Kafka-connect, and I need a solution to send metric to datadog as well that Kafka- connect is stopped

Answer (score 1):

Metrics are usually sent by running applications, and a metric for application start / stop does not make sense.

Kafka / Kafka connect stopping should generate either an event, or you can check the log in Datadog (after setting up log push to Datadog) to detect a shutdown.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  we use different connectors for markets, we want to keep track of how many connectors started and closed on datadog, when staring systemctl start kafka works and applocation starts and sends metric but when stopping we use systemctl stop kafka its stopping app and not sending datadod metric. and logs i can see logs but i want metric.

Comment: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/logs_to_metrics/ this might help